# TypeScript to JSDoc: global/interface

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm currently converting a project from TypeScript to JavaScript with JSDoc. I'm trying to do the following but with JSDoc:

```
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
        toBeTheSameAsRemote: (expected: string) => CustomMatcherResult;
    }
  }
}
```

I've come up with this so far:

```
/**
 * @namespace jest
 */
/**
 * @interface Matchers
 * @memberof jest
 */
```

The example in https://jsdoc.app/tags-interface.html doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In my pure JavaScript project I use these JSDoc enties to make WebStorm recognize the extensions (I put them before the `expect.extend` call):

```
/**
 * @function JestMatchers#toBeTheSameAsRemote
 */
/**
 * @function Matchers#toBeTheSameAsRemote
 */
```

The first is needed for `expect(...).toBeTheSameAsRemote()` and the second is needed for `expect(...)` **`.not.`**`toBeTheSameAsRemote()` to work.
Should your matcher have their own parameters, you can document them here with the `@param` tag - unfortunately you will need to duplicate them.