# Can't Jest extend matchers types with JSDoc

Tags: jestjs

I'm using ESM (`type: "module"`).

I have a custom matcher:

```
import { expect } from "@jest/globals";

expect.extend({
  anyDateString: function (received) {
    const dateValue = new Date(received);
    const pass = dateValue instanceof Date && !isNaN(dateValue);
    const messageGenerator = (not) => () => `expected ${received} ${not}to be a valid date string value`;

    return {
      pass,
      message: messageGenerator(pass ? 'not ' : '')
    };
  },
});
```

I'm using JSDoc to enforce types, so when I'm trying to use the matcher, I get the following error:

```
expect.anyDateString(); // Property 'anyDateString' does not exist on type 'Expect<MatcherState>'.ts(2339)
```

I tried to add:

```
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
        anyDateString: (expected: string) => any;
    }
    interface Expect {
        anyDateString: (expected: string) => any;
    }
  }
}
```

But no luck.
the matcher is working as expected.

Comment: Asked before, also no solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988405/typescript-to-jsdoc-global-interface

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the jest version and had a quite rough gestation phase. Nowadays (jest 28+) you declare them as

```
declare module 'expect' {
    interface Matchers<R> {
        anyDateString: (expected: string) => any;
    }
}
```

Of course you still need the old `namespace jest` declaration if you use the ambient `expect` and not the ESM-style `import { expect } from '@jest/globals';`